# Can I add jquery script to iframe button

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I load an iframe into my html. In the iframe loaded there is a button.
After clicking this button user should be redirected to a specific URL.

I wrote below script but this does not work. The effect is that iframe stays on the site and the redirection from the script doesnt happen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Yes_text").click(function(){
    window.location.href="my_url"
  })
});
```

These are the options I tried.
The HTML for this button:

```
<td class="regularButton" 
 style="padding-top:0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:-2px;padding-right:-2px;padding-left:2ex;padding-right:2ex;" 
 dir="ltr" id="Yes_text"><nobr>Yes</nobr></td>
```

**EDIT**:
I played a little in the console with function with `console.log` suggested in comments and it seems that my script is loaded but later overwritten by some script I cant change.
Another thing I tried is as follows:

```
var old_function = $("#Yes_text").closest('table').attr('buttonaction');
                var my_function = 'open_new_page();'
                var new_button_action = my_function;

                console.log(new_button_action);
                $("#Yes_text").closest('table').attr('buttonaction', new_button_action);

                window.open("https://wp.pl");
            }
```

This worked while in console, not in my dev environment.

What do I do wrong here?

Karolina

Comment: Is the code for the button in the page of the iframe? Does the iframe load jQuery? - also you need `window.open("my_url","_top"); ` if you want to change the whole page

Comment: hi, yes the code for the button is in the page of the iframe. In the page of iframe, in the header they have jquery lib but its different version, its in 1.9.1 and also 1.2.1, I also have the latest (3.3.1) version loaded inmy html where I open the iframe.

Comment: i changed `window.location.href="my_url"` to `window.open("my_url","_top");` but this did not help. My page is lateropened in the iframe...

Comment: Any messages in the console? (F12) - You cannot have TWO jQuery versions in the same page

Comment: Do you see "loading" in the console if you have `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Yes_text").click(function(){ console.log("loading");
    window.open("my_url","_top"); 
  })
});`

Comment: hi, no the log does not show in the console...

Comment: the log was displayed in the console only when I tried it in developers tools - I added an `<a>` element and run the script on it..

Answer (score -1):

Try the below:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="regularButton"
                style="padding-top:0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:-2px;padding-right:-2px;padding-left:2ex;padding-right:2ex;"
                dir="ltr" onclick="newDoc()">
                <nobr>Yes</nobr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function newDoc() {
        window.location.assign("https://www.google.co.in");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There a ZERO need for changing `window.location.href="my_url"` to ` window.location.assign("my_url")` unless you need to mock a location change - and inline scripting is not better than unobtrusive event handling